# TextColumn error with style TextBox readonly in DataGrid WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a code

```
 <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Số TT" Binding="{Binding Path=STT}" Width="600">
                <DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                        <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="true" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Mod10" Binding="{Binding Path=mod10}" Width="400"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
```

I want to create ReadOnlyTextboxcolumn can select text in datagrid WPF
But When I try to manipulate the cells quickly, it shows an editable error, shows an error message and locks all the remaining cells that can not be selected.
[This error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTPmg.png)

Comment: Why not Set the IsReadOnly property in the DataGridTextColumn directly. You dont need the Editing ElementStyle

Comment: I want the text in cell can be selected as ReadOnly in Windows form. If i set readOnly for columns I can select it

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IsReadOnly` of `DataGridTextColumn` to make it read only. No need of a style in given scenario.

```
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Số TT" Width="auto" Binding="{Binding STT }" IsReadOnly="True" />
```

Comment: I want the text in cell can be selected as ReadOnly in Windows form. If i set readOnly for columns I can select it